# Sync Joplin between desktop (Ubuntu) and phone (android)

Tags: ubuntu, sync, android, dropbox

The note taking app Joplin should be able to sync files between a phone and a desktop. However, I have not managed to get this to work.

I authorized the same dropbox account on both the desktop and the phone. However, when I sync on the phone the notes that are there on the desktop do not appear.

Below Synchronize it says (on both devices):

```
Completed: [recent date]
Last error: Error: POST files/list_folder: Error (409): {"error_summary": "path/not_found/..." , ...}
```

Joplin:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cozic.joplin

Comment: As I have seen you have already created a [post in the Joplin forum](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/sync-between-desktop-and-phone/18557). The chance to get an working answer to solve your problems is IMHO much higher there.

Comment: @Robert, that sounds likely. I much prefer stackexchange in terms of readability and searchability though. If I get an answer there and not here I will be sure to come back here and answer my question. That will likely help out someone else encountering the same issue later.

Comment: @Kovothe me too. But from my experience asking for an application where there is no tag available with the name of the app has a very low chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that the sync with Dropbox on the desktop was not working. This was caused by the "fix" explained [here](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/joplin-i-love-you-but-this-is-driving-me-nuts-dropbox/10842/3) to avoid continuous messages that Joplin uploaded a new file to dropbox. Unfortunately the fix (now?) breaks things. So I had to undo it and now everything is working.